# Referring to matched value in Rust

Tags: rust, match

Suppose I have this code:

```
fn non_zero_rand() -> i32 {
    let x = rand();
    match x {
        0 => 1,
        _ => x,
    }
}
```

Is there a concise way to put the `rand()` in the match, and then bind it to a value. E.g. something like this:

```
fn non_zero_rand() -> i32 {
    match let x = rand() {
        0 => 1,
        _ => x,
    }
}
```

Or maybe:

```
fn non_zero_rand() -> i32 {
    match rand() {
        0 => 1,
        _x => _x,
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second example should work

Comment: `_x => _x` will *work*, but it isn't semantically correct. A leading underscore means "this value is unused", so it isn't appropriate here.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A match arm that consists of just an identifier will match any value, declare a variable named as the identifier, and move the value to the variable. For example:

```
match rand() {
    0 => 1,
    x => x * 2,
}
```

A more general way to create a variable and match it is using the `@` pattern:

```
match rand() {
    0 => 1,
    x @ _ => x * 2,
}
```

In this case it is not necessary, but it can come in useful when dealing with patterens that match many different values, such as [range patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#matching-ranges-of-values-with-):

```
match c {
    None => Category::Empty,
    Some(ascii @ 0..=127) => Category::Ascii(ascii),
    Some(latin1 @ 160..=255) => Category::Latin1(latin1),
    _ => Category::Invalid,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1bd1d23f75c18703f264087fa0d76830)

Comment: `x` and the unbound value are the same thing so you should just be able to use `x => x`?

Comment: @Lee Good point. I've expanded the answer to show more realistic usage of `@` pattern.

Comment: For what it's worth: It's also helpful for matching on multiple patterns like `token @ ( '{' | '}' | '(' | ')' ) => something_with(token)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind the pattern to a name:

```
fn non_zero_rand() -> i32 {
    match rand() {
        0 => 1, // 0 is a refutable pattern so it only matches when it fits.
        x => x, // the pattern is x here,
                // which is non refutable, so it matches on everything
                // which wasn't matched already before
    }
}
```