# Is there a way to match two enum variants and also bind the matched variant to a variable?

Tags: rust

I have this enum:

```
enum ImageType {
    Png,
    Jpeg,
    Tiff,
}
```

Is there any way to match one of the first two, and also bind the matched value to a variable? For example:

```
match get_image_type() {
    Some(h: ImageType::Png) | Some(h: ImageType::Jpeg) => {
        // Lots of shared code
        // that does something with `h`
    },
    Some(ImageType::Tiff) => { ... },
    None => { ... },
}
```

That syntax doesn't work, but is there any that does?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you are asking how to bind the value inside the first case. If so, you can use this:

```
match get_image_type() {
    // use @ to bind a name to the value
    Some(h @ ImageType::Png) | Some(h @ ImageType::Jpeg) => {
        // Lots of shared code that does something with `h`
    },
    Some(ImageType::Tiff) => { ... },
    None => { ... }
}
```

If you want to also get the bound value outside of the `match` statement, you can use the following:

```
let matched = match get_image_type() {
    Some(h @ ImageType::Png) | Some(h @ ImageType::Jpeg) => {
        // Lots of shared code that does something with `h`
        Some(h)
    },
    Some(h @ ImageType::Tiff) => {
        // ...
        Some(h)
    },
    None => {
        // ...
        None
    },
};
```

In that case, though, it might be better to simply `let h = get_image_type()` first, and then `match h` (thanks to [BHustus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49329586/is-there-a-way-to-match-two-enum-variants-and-also-bind-the-matched-variant-to-a/49329634#comment85662536_49329634)).

Note the use of the `h @ <value>` syntax to bind the variable name `h` to the matched value ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40962017/6073823)).

Comment: It's worth noting that, for this *specific* example, it may be clearer to do `let h = get_image_type()` and then `match h` which doesn't return anything, unless there's some change made in the `match` block. As the second example stands, it seems redundant. This is still a good example of the `@` variable-binding syntax.