# Match on a field(member variable) of struct

Tags: rust

Given the following code

```rs
enum shape {
  Circle,
  Square,
  Rectangle
}

struct A {
  b: shape,
  c: String
}

struct Plan {
 items : Vec<A>
}

impl Plan {

fn draw_shapes() {
    self.items.iter().find_map(|d| match ??? { // How to match on a field of struct?
            shapes::Circle => draw_circle(d),
            shapes::Square => draw_square(d),
            shapes::Rectanble => draw_rectangle(d),
        })
    }
}
}
```

I want to match a **field** of `struct A` and call the respective draw functions.

Comment: What about `match d.b`?

Comment: You also don't need the wildcard.

Comment: SO is not a forum

Comment: @Stargateur How is that related here?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It's not mean to answer every basic question like that, first there is countless of similar question on SO, OP just didn't show any search effort, no code formation, unclear and didn't even read the rust book. This question look more like a forum question, a reddit question or discord question fine ask on these platform such bad question but I don't want this in SO.

Comment: You should probably call that enum `Shape`.

Comment: @Stargateur As long as this question was not already asked, it is suitable for SO (even if worth downvotes) as basic as it may be, and I couldn't find any duplicate, not even "How do I access fields in Rust".

Comment: @Stargateur This question is fine. I think you're over-reacting here. There are far worse questions to pick on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109872/how-do-you-access-enum-values-in-rust/33723601#33723601 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961938/referring-to-matched-value-in-rust/40962017#40962017 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41390457/how-to-match-struct-fields-in-rust/41394755#41394755 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429501/how-do-i-conditionally-check-if-an-enum-is-one-variant-or-another/51429606#51429606 @ChayimFriedman to name a few

Comment: @Stargateur I consider none of these a duplicate, but you can disagree.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman `match d.b` worked! If you want to put that as answer I'll accept it. Not sure why @Stargateur thinks this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to match over the property access on the struct, in this case you would be using `match d.b`.

```rust
    self.items.iter().find_map(|d| match d.b { // How to match on a field of struct?
            shapes::Circle => draw_circle(d),
            shapes::Square => draw_square(d),
            shapes::Rectanble => draw_rectangle(d),
        })
    }
```

This is because `match` blocks match over any expression, not just an identifier.